# Linux LiveCD (or LiveUSB) with custom xorg.conf

Tags: linux, display, livecd, x-windows

Is there some Live Linux distribution (on CD, DVD or USB), which allow one to use specific xorg.conf file, i.e. specific X11 configuration?

The problem I am trying to solve is to find Linux Live distribution for web browsing which would work well with NEC LCD 22WV monitor.  It is supposedly DDCCCI capable, but X.Org X Window System autoconfiguration fails to detect proper modeline, and uses fallback 800x600 screen resolution, instead of preferred screen resolution of 1680x1050.

Comment: I guess that something like Remastersys (or its equivalent for other distributions) might be a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a customized [ubuntu installation on an USB stick](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/LiveUsbPendrivePersistent). [Modding the Gentoo LiveCD](http://forums.gentoo.org/viewtopic-t-580369.html) sounds more fun though.

Comment: Is it possible to generate such customized LiveCD from MS Windows, or other Live distribution?

Comment: @Jakub The Ubuntu tools needs to be run from an Ubuntu system, but an Ubuntu LiveCD is good enough. Just try out their `usb-creator`.